# Combine Google Slides presentations via API?

Tags: google-slides-api, google-slides

How can I programmatically copy slides from one Google Slides presentation to another?  Ideally, App Scripts or something along those lines but running something on a local Linux server would work well as well.

For example, perhaps every N hours, we
a) delete all existing slides from Presentation A
b) copy all the slides from Presentation B to A
c) copy all the slides from Presentation C to A (after the slides from B)
d) copy all the slides from Presentation D to A (after the slides from C)

Or, if it is between June 1 and June 30, copy the slides from Presentation E to A but ignore Presentation E before June 1 or after June 30.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't currently available in the Slides API. There's a feature request on the issue tracker here you can follow for updates: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761705

Comment: is it possible to get elements from different slides and combine using apps Script?